# How can I list all the resource groups in my azure account using python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I am completely new to Azure. I cannot find a proper documentation of Python SDK for Azure anywhere. I want to access all the resources in my azure account using python. Starting with listing all the resource groups present in my account. How can I do that?

Also, please share link of proper documentation if present.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good article to get started: [Manage Azure resources and resource groups with Python](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/resource-manager-python-resources-and-groups/)

This is how the python code looks like (taken from the article):

```
import os

from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

subscription_id = os.environ.get(
    'AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID',
    '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111') # your Azure Subscription Id
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID'],
    secret=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    tenant=os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID']
)
client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

for item in client.resource_groups.list():
    print_item(item)
```

Comment: where can I get my azure credentials?

Comment: In this example they use a service principal to connecto to Azure. You also find an article how to create one. Just read it.

Comment: Hi, Is there anyway we can get the list of newly created Resource groups within a particular time? say for eg. I want to get the list of RGs created in my subscription within last min.

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-example-list-resource-groups)

```
import os
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "Your_ID"

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
group_list = resource_client.resource_groups.list()

for group in group_list:
    print(group)
```